# How do I get the length of a string in Perl?

Tags: perl, string

What is the Perl equivalent of `strlen()`?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`length($string)`

```
perldoc -f length

   length EXPR
   length  Returns the length in characters of the value of EXPR.  If EXPR is
           omitted, returns length of $_.  Note that this cannot be used on an
           entire array or hash to find out how many elements these have.  For
           that, use "scalar @array" and "scalar keys %hash" respectively.

           Note the characters: if the EXPR is in Unicode, you will get the num-
           ber of characters, not the number of bytes.  To get the length in
           bytes, use "do { use bytes; length(EXPR) }", see bytes.
```

Comment: What if the string contains embedded zeros (say, as a result of reading part of or an entire ***binary file*** into a string)? 'length' may not be the exact equivalent.

Comment: @PeterMortensen the question was for an equivalent to `strlen`, which also stops on an embedded zero.

Answer (score 45):

Although 'length()' is the correct answer that should be used in any sane code, [Abigail's length horror](https://web.archive.org/web/20071024192714/http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?abigail_s_length_horror) should be mentioned, if only for the sake of Perl lore.

Basically, the trick consists of using the return value of the catch-all transliteration operator:

```
print "foo" =~ y===c;   # prints 3
```

y///c replaces all characters with themselves (thanks to the complement option 'c'), and returns the number of character replaced (so, effectively, the length of the string).

Comment: y's counting modes don't actually modify the string, so they will work fine even on readonly values.

Comment: @Yanick I can't read the link of "Abigail's length horror" so can you explain this please? I know this topic is old, but there are newcomers like me who are interested.

Comment: @bashophil belatedly changed link to an archive.org one to avoid social text login

Comment: Putting links in answers is really annoying.  Even the archive.org link for "Abigail's length horror" returns only a login screen.  Just describe the content or remove the totally useless and time-wasting link.

Answer (score 41):

```
length($string)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `length()` function:

```
$string ='String Name';
$size=length($string);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO!  I'm not sure what this answer adds, more than ten years later, after this question was asked and answered?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use this, since length($string) is simpler and more readable, but I came across some of these while looking through code and was confused, so in case anyone else does, these also get the length of a string:

```
my $length = map $_, $str =~ /(.)/gs;
my $length = () = $str =~ /(.)/gs;
my $length = split '', $str;
```

The first two work by using the global flag to match each character in the string, then using the returned list of matches in a scalar context to get the number of characters. The third works similarly by splitting on each character instead of regex-matching and using the resulting list in scalar context