# Perl Program to Read a Text File, Search for text within the File and copy the text to a new file

Tags: regex, perl

This is a fixed format and this is what you see when I open up in notepad or ultraedit. This is just some sample data, but my text file has about 200,000 lines and multiple directories like you see in the example. So basically I am trying to append the path that you see where it says " Directory of  V: \word" and add  "V:\word" to the end of the line and copy it down up until it sees the new " Directory of V:\word\excels" and adds "V:\word\excels" after the fact and so on and so on. Would you be able to help me out and possibly throw a dog a bone? Thanks and much appreciated!

```
 Directory of V:\word
04/30/2007  11:49 AM        938,458   BUILTIN\Admin       Filename.pdf
04/06/2012  01:13 PM          3,801   AMERICAS\DoeJ       Filename3.pdf
01/11/2007  12:05 PM         26,624   BUILTIN\Admin       Filename2.doc
08/01/2007  11:57 AM         18,432   BUILTIN\Admin       Filename5.xls
 Directory of V:\word\excels
03/03/2010  10:42 AM         35,840   AMERICAS\DavisF     Billing3-3.xls
02/24/2010  10:31 AM         34,380   AMERICAS\StewartF   Allie2-24.xls
```

This is what I am trying to accomplish

```
 Directory of V:\word
04/30/2007  11:49 AM        938,458   BUILTIN\Admin       Filename.pdf     V:\word
04/06/2012  01:13 PM          3,801   AMERICAS\DoeJ       Filename3.pdf    V:\word
01/11/2007  12:05 PM         26,624   BUILTIN\Admin       Filename2.doc    V:\word
08/01/2007  11:57 AM         18,432   BUILTIN\Admin       Filename5.xls    V:\word
 Directory of V:\word\excels
03/03/2010  10:42 AM         35,840   AMERICAS\DavisF     Billing3-3.xls   V:\word\excels
02/24/2010  10:31 AM         34,380   AMERICAS\StewartF   Allie.xls        V:\word\excels
```

This is what I have in perl: I'm still stuck, but I think I'm making some progress.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl 
    use strict 
    use warnings 
    use autodie

    open (MYFILE, 'List.txt');
    my $str = " Directory of V:\word";
    while (<MYFILE>)
    {
        chomp;
        ($Date, $Time, $Size, $User, $Filename) = split("\t");
        print $Date, $Time, $Size, $User, $Filename, substr $str,14;

        print "$_\n";
    }
    close (MYFILE);
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: @toolic - Which topic would best suffice for my issue on perlintro?

Comment: Please fix the title and give a step by step desccription of what you hope to achieve. Basically, this is helping people to help you.  I read the description and couldn't make sense of it. Also, post whatever code you have tried, or try something and post it.

Comment: You don't need `<br>` in your posts. Just add two new lines if you need a line break.

Comment: OK, that's a bit better.  So it sounds like what you don't know how to do is match a string in a certain format, and append it onto the end of the subsequent lines until you get another match.

Comment: You have a cboice.  You can use basic [string functions](http://perlmaven.com/string-functions-length-lc-uc-index-substr), or [regular expression matching](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).  These links will give you something to read and consider while you wait to see if your question gets reopened.

Comment: The length of a string in `$S` is `length($S)`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223393/how-do-i-get-the-length-of-a-string-in-perl  --- Also `say` is closely related to `print`, I would probably prefer print here though I don't recall why.  You may have to combine length and index with some math to get what you want out of substr.

Comment: In that while loop, each line is put in `$_` in case that is not obvious.

Comment: If you get something partially working, edit your code above.  People like to see partial work.

Comment: Please `use strict`, `use warnings`, and `use autodie` (or check `open()` for errors).  You won't regret getting into those habits.

Answer (score 1):

[@Pichi's one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18526894/132382) will do what you want if your file is given on stdin or passed as an argument.  Since it is a bit opaque, here's what it is doing in an explicit manner:

```
# What's this doing?  perl -lpe'/ Directory of (.*)/?$a=$1:($_.="\t$a")'

my $suffix;                              # Pichi uses $a, a quietly special var I usually avoid

while (defined(my $line = <ARGV>)) {     # Magic ARGV filehandle - stdin or arguments
  chomp($line);                          # Remove newline (-l switch)

  if ($line =~ / Directory of (.*)/) {   # This is the ?: clause
    $suffix = $1;
  } else {
    $line .= "\t$suffix";
  }

  print "$line\n";                       # Print (-p) with newline (-l, again)
}
```

Perl's convenient one-liners actually do a bit more than that (e.g., `$/` and `$\` are explicitly set, and the `print` is error-checked), but that's essentially the approach.

Answer (score 0):

Why not awk?

```
awk '/ Directory of /{at=$3;print;next}{print $0""FS""at}' your_file
```

Perl:

```
perl -lne 'if(/ Directory of (.*)/){$a=$1;print}else{$_.="\t".$a;print}' your_file
```

if you want to do an inline replacement:

```
perl -i -lne 'if(/ Directory of (.*)/){$a=$1;print}else{$_.="\t".$a;print}' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using a Perl script (good opportunity to learn about it):

First, in order to write in a NEW file you need to open two files: FILE1 would be the one where you have the information to read, FILE2 the one where you will write. So, open the first one with "reading" options ('<') and the second one with "writing" options ('>'). More info. about ['openfile' here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).

Then, when you are using "WHILE" I will recommend you to take each sentence in one variable ...

```
while ($line =<$file1>) 
{    ... 
     ...
}
```

... and depending on ([info. about 'if statement'](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements)) the beginning of the sentence (['regular expressions'](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)) do an action/printing or another.

To print the directory at the end of the sentence, keep also the lines with the directory information ('if') in a variable. You can also eliminate the part of the sentence that you are not interested on using the useful 'regular expressions' (aka 'regex').

Easy ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple:

```
perl -lpe'/ Directory of (.*)/?$a=$1:($_.="\t$a")'
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your answer.

Comment: Sorry there was bug. I have fixed it. You can use it placing file name after this command or pipe output of some other command there.