# I think this code finds string length. What's actually going on here?

Tags: regex, perl

I've been tasked with converting some code from Perl to Python, and I ran into this bit of code that confused me:

```
my $length = map $_, $root =~ /(.)/gs;
```

From the variable names and testing, I've determined it gets the length of a string, but it seems like a really bizarre and unreadable way to do it. Is there any reason why someone might use that instead of `length($root)` or the horrible `$root =~ y///c`, as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223393/how-do-i-get-the-length-of-a-string-in-perl)? I want to make sure I'm not missing some functionality based on some strange Perl behavior that I don't know about.

Comment: Another one, `my $len_chars = split '', $str;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In list context, the m// operator with the /g modifier returns a list of all captures, which in this case is each character in the string. The map is a no-op, but in scalar context returns the number of elements that would be in the list it generated, so the result is the number of characters in the string. The m// operator works differently in scalar context, so this intermediary step is needed. A similar idiom is:

```
my $length = () = $root =~ /(.)/gs;
```

This is generally used for more complex match counting, since the [length](https://perldoc.pl/functions/length) function is perfectly suitable and much more efficient.

Comment: In list context, the `m//` operator returns a list of all captures regardless of whether `/g` modifier was used or not. The `/g` makes the `m//` operator find all matches, which is necessary here.

Answer (score 4):

The only difference I can think of is that under 5.6.x's broken Unicode model, length() returns number of chars but /(.)/gs returns number of bytes. From 5.8.0 onwards both return number of characters. 5.6.0 was released 19 years ago, and 5.8.0 17 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why the original coder took that 'long' approach to get the length of `$root`.

Let me dissect the code piece by piece:

The code below would return a list containing each character in `$root` that matches `.` (Basically every character).

```
$root =~ /(.)/gs
```

The list generated is then mapped which basically does nothing. In scalar context, map would return the number of elements:

```
map $_, (list)
```

Then this value is stored in `$length`.